# Diagonally wrap content in div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'd like the content in the in the `#content-body-text` `div` to be diagonally aligned against the rectangle which is contained in the `div` `#book4`, basically allowing the text in `#content-body-text` to shrink down in width as we get closer to the bottom.

I'm not really sure what the best approach to do this is.  Right now, `#book4` is a `div` with just a background of a diagonal rectangle.  I have thought about just doing a background fill on `#book4` and then a `transform: rotate(xxxdeg)` to replace the `div`'s background image, however if I do this I am still not sure how to wrap the `#content-body-text` around this rotated div.

this screenshot shows what I am trying to do:
[image]

I have a jsfiddle with my sample layout available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/agola/6juayuhq/).

I am open to any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: Check out this post: http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/

Comment: HTML elements are rectangles, shaping content is only experimental at the moment. = https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape